# How to use phpdoc for documenting laravel 5.1 controllers?

Tags: laravel-5.1, phpdoc

I want to document my project being created in Laravel 5.1. I am using phpdoc for that purpose. However, the phpdoc is not generating the required documentation for documenting laravel 5.1 controllers. Can anybody help with demo?

Comment: what have you actually tried so far?

Comment: I have phpdoc installed for documentation. I have done one function test as $phpdoc -f functiontest.php -t docs/. It gives the required documentation. However I want to document my controllers say HomeController.php and want to know how to do it. I have put my documentation below the namespace and above the namespace but the documentation is not generated.